# How to get Start of day and end of day in moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get start of day and end of day in `moment.js` in `Date` object format.

This is what I have tried so: far

```js
console.log('today', moment().startOf('day').toDate());

let UTC = moment.utc();
let local = moment(UTC).local();

console.log('momentYest', moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate());
console.log('momentendYest', local.startOf(1, 'day').subtract(1, 'day').toDate());
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

why is `.toDate()` changing T00:00 to T07:00 ?
I need to start from T00:00 to 23:59

Answer (score 0):

The time is displayed in [UTC Format (ISO 8601)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), every JavaScript Date is stored in this format and adjusts automatically to the local timezone. The Routines like .getTime() or .toString() on a date instance, will return the values respective to the timezone of the environment. While .toJSON(), which is the result you see at your screenshot, returns the time in ISO Format.

If you want the time displayed matching to your timezone make use of `.format()` instead  of `.toDate()`.

From momentjs.com

```js
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // August 23rd 2021, 1:09:15 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Monday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Aug 23rd 21
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2021 escaped 2021
moment().format();                          // 2021-08-23T01:09:15+02:00
```

The `.toDate()` function is returning a new Date-instance, so you have the correct time you desired available. If you use `.toDate().getTimezoneOffset()` it should return the 7 hrs and also `.toDate().getTime()` will return 00:00:00 or 23:59:59.